# How to find filename with wildcard and vise versa?

Tags: vb.net, file

I have a base filename called "myExcel.xlsm" i'm looking for, I want to find additional files that start with the base filename and will have a extension "Ext*" << could be Ext1, Ext2..... I have no problem finding the additional files. My problem is when i'm looking for the additional files "myExcelExt1.xlsm", i want to be able to find the base filename "myExcel.xlsm". Here is my code:

```
Dim pathway As String = "C:\myFolder\"
Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetFiles(pathway, "myExcel" & "Ext*.xlsm")
    If dirs.Length >= 1 Then
        msgbox("Additional Reports: " & vbCrLf & String.Join(", ", dirs.Select(Function(x) Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)))
    End If
```

Comment: No, it is not duplicate, the other one is finding wildcard in path, i'm looking for specific filename but want to find other filename with that part of the base name.

Comment: if the file i'm searching is "myExcel.xlsm" and i'm looking for another additional file using the "Ext*.xlsm" i wll find them. But if i'm searching for "myExcelExt1.xlsm" and i'm looking for additional files associated with it, i'm not finding "myExcel.xlsm" or "myExcelExt2.xlsm".

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible using GetFiles, but a possible workaround would be to get all files in the directory then loop round them and do if FIleName.Contains?

Comment: @RyanThomas that works but, when the file i'm searching has the Ext, contains will not find the base excel file.

Comment: @TheManIsTheWind Can you do a For each file As FileInfo In GetFiles....
Then use file.FullName because I that will have the extension I beileve... or do GetFiles("*.xsl") like you have? Sorry not sure what you mean